# SharePoint functions very slow

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem

The SharePoint i'm working on is very slow. Does anyone have any experience on what the issue could be? I believe the problem is within the SP server 'cause all the site collections are slow. If you have any experience i would appreciate it. By the way it is a on premise SP.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Performance issue usually comes down to a too weak hardware. So go ahead and check memory usage, disk usage and processor usage. If anyone of these run at 100% over a period of time, you've found the issue.

To solve this, add more virtual processor cores (if processor runs at 100%), add more RAM if memory usage is 100% and more disk if you lack disk space.

Do the same for the SQL Server.

If all hardware parameters are fine, then check the health analyzer to see if you find anything interesting there. Also keep an eye of the ULS log which usually floods if you have serious errors in your farm.

That's the normal starting point when you lack performance.

Comment: thank you Benny. i will certainly follow up on your solutions